# How to preserve the order of objects in a Java collection?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have following method which works fine however returns the objects in the **alphabetical orders** whenever being called from calling method :-

```
  public List<Object> getExportDataFromView() {

try {

  String selectQuery = "SELECT UNIQUE_ID, DATE, CODE, PRODUCT_CODE, "
      + " MESSAGE AS MESSAGE_TEXT, SOURCE, COMPANY_ID, REMARK, BATCH, COUNTRY, PRODUCT_CODE_SCHEME, EXTERNAL_TRANSACTION_ID, RETURN_CODE, CORRELATION_ID, BUSINESS_PROCESS, BATCH_EXPIRY_DATE "
      + " FROM \"test\".\"my-systems.Company::views.Export_Data_View\" "
      + " WHERE COMPANY_ID = 'C100' "
      + " ORDER BY DATE DESC";

  Query q = this.em.createNativeQuery(selectQuery, ExportData.class);

  return q.getResultList();

} catch (Exception e) {
  return null;

} finally {
  this.em.close();

}
```

}

Whenever this method is called from another calling method, the List returned is in sorted order (alphabetically). However, in the JPA Entity class of ExportData.java, the fields are declared in original order like below :-

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "\"my-systems.Company::views.Export_Data_View\"", schema="\"test\"")
public class ExportData implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String UNIQUE_ID;

    private String CODE;

    private String PRODUCT_CODE;

    private String MESSAGE_TEXT;

    private String SOURCE;
```

Is there any way to preserve the same order as declared in Entity class rather than being sorted without changing the return type i.e. List.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: A `List` preserves order in that items stay in the order they are added (unless you take action to change it, eg.  by sorting the list). So given your query result is ordered, if you add each item to your list in the order you retrieve it, you should be fine. Other collections, eg. `Map` and `Set` do not always maintain order.

Comment: I tried this but still getting sorted      Query q = this.em.createNativeQuery(selectQuery, ExportData.class);

      List<Object> finalResult = null;
      if(null!=q && !q.getResultList().isEmpty()){
        finalResult = new ArrayList <>();
        for(Object obj: q.getResultList()){
          finalResult.add(obj);
        }
      }
      return finalResult;
      //return q.getResultList();

Comment: What ordering do you think is being declared in the entity class?

Comment: Which database and which JPA implementation do you use?

Comment: I'm using SAP Hana database with Olingo JPA i.e. <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>

   <artifactId>olingo-odata2-jpa-processor-api</artifactId>

   <version>2.0.10</version>

Comment: You're talking in the same breath about both the  **sorted** order of the result list, and the **declared** order of the fields of the Entity.  The two have nothing to do with each other.  Which order is important to you?

Comment: I want to keep the declared order and not the sorted order from the resultlist

Comment: The order of the result is determined by the `ORDER BY` clause of the query that created the result.  There is _no other_ "declared" order.  If you prefer results in a different order, you must either change the `ORDER BY` clause to get the desired order directly, or apply an in-memory sort to the result to put it in the order you want.

Comment: You have to be more clear regarding which order you mean. Do you mean the order of the returned rows? Or do you mean the order of the fields within each row? Please clarify. Both orders are given by the query and have nothing to do with the declaration order of the fields within the entity.

Comment: I mean the order of the fields within each row in the list here. The List contains the objects of ExportData class and in the ExportData class, there are fields like UNIQUE_ID, Code, Product_Code. Order of these fields are getting sorted alphabetically which I do not want. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Could you provide examples of your current "wrong" output and of the desired "correct" output,  along with an explanation of why the one is wrong and the other is correct?

Comment: I have taken the screenshot of response which I'm getting here. https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/doubtstackoverflow/Sample+OData+structure.jpg   If you notice all these attributes are in alphabetical order. These fields are not declared alphabetically in ExportData class. Not sure how it is getting sorted then. I do not want in the sorted order but in the same order that were declared in the ExportData class.

Comment: What you're looking at there is not "your list", it's an XML (I'm guessing) _representation_ of the data that was in your list.  The XML serialization/marshalling tool that prepared that XML chose, for whatever reason, to list the attributes of your entity in that order.  Depending on the XML tool, maybe you can alter that choice, maybe not. But even if you don't have the choice, you shouldn't care: it's the same entity, regardless of how the fields are ordered.